# Software about CPU and battery statistics

Tags: gratis, windows-8, battery, system-monitor, statistics

I am looking for software which has good statistics about CPU and can stay minimized, with a system tray showing CPU stats. My notebook is overheating sometimes, I want to see clock speed if possible and the temperature as well.

Does somebody know a freeware one?

Comment: Which OS? - it does make a difference!

Comment: Sry - Windows 8

Comment: What kind of statistics do you want to see? Overall utilization, per-core utilization, clock speed, etc?

Comment: Well my notebook is overheating sometimes, I want to see clock speed if possible and the temperature as well

Comment: Christian, you can always [edit] your question. Putting essential information in comments is no good idea, as not everybody walks through all of them. Unor did that for you last time, I will do so now, next time is your turn :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Core Temp](http://www.alcpu.com/CoreTemp/) might be the program you are looking for. It offers trayicons where you can see the temperature, clock speed, an overheat protection which warns you and is able to shutdown Windows or close programs automatically. It also has a Windows sidebar widget, but as far as I know Windows 8 doesn't support the sidebar anymore. I don't know if it has battery statistics as well (I don't have a notebook to test it), but it should cover most of your needs. And it's free!

[image: Core Temp main window]

If you care to analyze your system in a more accurate way, [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/) is also able to show you the clock speed with GPU usage, and a few more things. Very similar to Process Explorer. Free as well. But don't forget, the built-in Windows 8 Task-Manager is already able to show you the CPU clock speed.